# I need to restart from the root command line

Tags: boot, shutdown, restart

I need help restarting/shutting down from the root command line, any commands I could use?
I don't like hard resetting

Answer (score 92):

```
shutdown -r now
```

would do restart.

```
shutdown -h now
```

will halt/shutdown the system.

In Ubuntu's case, you can use `reboot` or `halt`, etc. They all invoke the `shutdown` command.

```
man reboot
```

may help.

Comment: "poweroff" works too to shutdown w/o reboot ;)

Answer (score 29):

For **shutting down**:

```
sudo poweroff
```

(It immediately stops all the processes and shuts down the computer.)

For **restarting**:

```
sudo reboot
```

**Edit**: Once you are already running as a root you needn't type *sudo*.

See here for more options:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-reboot-linux/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-reboot-linux/

http://archive.oreilly.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=p/poweroff

Comment: The OP mentioned that he is already inside a root shell, so no `sudo` is required. Otherwise your answer is ok, except that you could add a bit additional explanations what those commands do... (because it appeared in the Low-Quality review queue because of its length)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for shutting down has already been given. You can reboot the system with

```
# reboot
```